# how to use a parameter in a app.module function

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a module to import which needs a variable for forRoot, for this, I need the application to be started and use a service to get:

```
export function getAuthConfig(configService: ConfigService):OauthConfig[] {    
      return configService.getOauthConfig();
}


function initializeAppFactory(httpClient: HttpClient, configService: ConfigService): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => httpClient.get(url)
  .pipe(
   tap((res) => {
    configService.loadAppConfig(<AppConfig>res);
   })
);
}

@NgModule({
providers: [
  ConfigService,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient, ConfigService],
    multi: true
  }
],
imports: [   
  OauthModule.forRoot(
  {
    configurations: getAuthConfig() //include configservice here
  })
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
declarations: [
 AppComponent
 ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the method in `configService` as static.

```
export class getOauthConfig {
    static getOauthConfig() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then in the module you can call it statically.

```
export function getAuthConfig():OauthConfig[] {    
      return ConfigService.getOauthConfig();
}


function initializeAppFactory(httpClient: HttpClient, configService: ConfigService): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => httpClient.get(url)
  .pipe(
   tap((res) => {
    configService.loadAppConfig(<AppConfig>res);
   })
);
}

@NgModule({
providers: [
  ConfigService,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient, ConfigService],
    multi: true
  }
],
imports: [   
  OauthModule.forRoot(
  {
    configurations: getAuthConfig() //include configservice here
  })
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
declarations: [
 AppComponent
 ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```